# Compare two colors in an image + Which is best to draw 3D points

Tags: c#, colors, 3d, compare, point

I know that it possible using the

> GetPixel()

but is it possible to let the sw to decide which one is lighter or darker than the other.

I'm going to use a depthMap Image & I want to compare the colors of the pixels.
After that ,I'm going to create a 3D point for each pixel depends on it color range, if it's light, it would be in the front. & so on.

Also, which is the simplest, fastest & the best way to draw a 3d point: OpenGl or WPF ?! or other suggestion ?!

Comment: You can convert RGB to another colourspace like HSV to compare luminosity of colours.

Comment: `bool firstDarkerOrSame = first.GetBrightness() <= second.GetBrightness()`

Comment: As for 3D points, is this related to the first part of the question? What framework are you using, and what are you trying to do? These will determine which is the simplest, fastest and best way to draw points in 3D space.

Comment: @ Jordan Trudgett , Edited

Comment: @Ahmed KRAIEM..  Works, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [algorithms](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/) for calculating lightness using RGB values. As for the point drawing - it depends on you performance requirements. On how many points you need to draw per frame. So WPF may appear fast enough for you needs. The simplest solution may be a WPF [Ellipse Shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.ellipse.aspx) wich is high level and as a result - slower. If it is not fast enough - you could go for a low level API, down to a [Visual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.aspx) layer. The OpenGL and DirectX are even closer to hardware. At this level there is no such thing as Point. The graphics device operates with polygons and textures, so you may need to create a 1x1 pixel texture to represent you Point, create a quad and map this texture to a quad. Pretty complex stuff for drawing a Point.

Comment: I'm going to represent an image as points depending on its map depth. I don't have any good background about OpenGL and DirectX. Besides, I need to finish this idea ASAP :)

Comment: What exactly you need to do with your image? Are you really need to draw separate pixels or a precalculated Bitmap can be created and drawn in single method call?

Comment: I want to represent it as 3D points in the 3D Space. I have the image & the depth map of it. I want to compare the depth Map pixels. If its has a lighter color, It would represented in the front of the 3rd dimensional, dark in the deep far & other range between the white -lets say- & the black would be in the middle between them depending on their colors.

Comment: For 3D visualization the DirectX/OpenGL is a good choice. I did similar thing, but using cubes for point representation [here](https://bitbucket.org/openminded/cubes).

Comment: So which one can I learn quickly DirectX or OpenGL?! & thanks indeed fro the link :)

Comment: I haven't had much experience with OpenGL. But they are both pretty complex and require a good understanding of how graphics hardware works. The DirectX has a good managed wrapper - SharpDX. The SharpDX itself has a Toolkit - a higher level API that hides some complexity.